# Red exclamation mark next to object in JNDI Tree

Tags: jndi, hazelcast, weblogic12c

I have successfully deployed a Hazelcast Resource Adapter to Weblogic 12c using a weblogic hazelcast template, which results in a Hazelcast Connection Factory (`Main#com.company.HazelcastCF`) and the resource itself (`Main#com.company.MyHazelcastResource`) showing up in the JNDI tree when I go through the server into `View JNDI Tree`. Everything is functional and ears that depend on this resource adapter deploy successfully, and can use my Hazelcast node without issue.

However, there is a peculiar red exclamation mark next to the two entries connected to my resource adapter in the JNDI tree, like this one:
[image: Red exclamation mark next to HazelcastCF]

How can I find out what causes this red exclamation mark to show up - and, assuming something is wrong, fix the underlying issue?

The following is the weblogic-ra.xml in META-INF for the resource adapter.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<weblogic-connector  xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-connector"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-connector
             http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-connector/1.0/weblogic-connector.xsd">

    <jndi-name>Main#com.company.MyHazelcastResource</jndi-name>
    <enable-access-outside-app>true</enable-access-outside-app>
    <enable-global-access-to-classes>true</enable-global-access-to-classes>
    <outbound-resource-adapter>
        <connection-definition-group>
            <connection-factory-interface>javax.resource.cci.ConnectionFactory</connection-factory-interface>
            <connection-instance>
                <jndi-name>Main#com.company.HazelcastCF</jndi-name>
                <connection-properties>
                    <pool-params>
                        <initial-capacity>1</initial-capacity>
                        <max-capacity>50</max-capacity>
                        <capacity-increment>1</capacity-increment>
                    </pool-params>
                </connection-properties>
            </connection-instance>
        </connection-definition-group>
    </outbound-resource-adapter>
</weblogic-connector>
```

And this is a screenshot of the whole JNDI Tree after only the resource adapter being deployed (note that whatever happens onMouseOver for the exclamation mark results in a JavaScript error in the console).

[image]

Comment: The red exclamation mark indicates that an exception was thrown when the console attempted to do a lookup of a bound object. This is because there's a referenced class or type that isn't available on the server where the name is being resolved.